# Laravel get relationship that hasn't been updated or doesn't exist within 24 hours

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models:

`Users` model `hasMany` `Payments` model

`Payments` model `belongsTo` `User` model

I am trying to get the users that either haven't been paid in over a day or never.  So the last related `Payment` needs to be greater than 24 hours or simply not exist.

So I went ahead and also created a `hasOne` helper model to get the latest `Payment` only but I'm kinda stuck where to go next.

I basically want to be able to do `User::needsPayment()-get()` and it would return all users that need to be paid because they haven't been paid in over 24 hours or have never been paid yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `hasOne`. You can do this pretty easily with the existing relationship and a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) on the `User` model:

```
class User extends Model {
    // payments relationship method
    public function payments() {
        return  $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }

    // query scope
    public function scopeNeedsPayment($query) {
        // constrain to users that don't have a payment in the past 24 hours
        $query->whereDoesntHave('payments', function ($query) {
            // below are two versions of the same statement; pick one.
            // the sql version may be more accurate if your web server and
            // your database server are in different timezones.

            // assumes "paid_at" is your field name

            // php version:
            $query->where('paid_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('-24 hours')));
            // sql version:
            $query->whereRaw('paid_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)');
        });
    }
}
```

With the above query scope defined, your code `User::needsPayment()-get()` should give you the records you're looking for.

Comment: The php version didn't work for some reason.  It was missing another `)` at the end but it still kept returning empty.  The SQL version worked and it's awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: @zen Sorry, silly typo. I have fixed it. No guarantees when coding in StackOverflow box. :) Instead of the manual date stuff, you can try using Carbon instead: `\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(24)`. Or you can just go with the sql version that worked.